# How to use structural information in a Transformer?

Tags: deep-learning, transformer, graph-neural-networks, gnn

I am performing a Neural Machine Translation (NMT) task. In my case, input data has relational information.

I know I can use a Graph Neural Network (GNN) and use a Graph2Seq model. But I can't find a good generational model for GNN.

So I want to use Transformer. But then the challenge is how can I embed structural information there? Is there any open source artefact for Relational Transformer that I can use out of the box?

Any pointers?

Comment: can you clarify the "relational information"?

Comment: Two nodes are connected by an edge with a relation. Think about a knowledge graph.

Comment: Would it make sense to define a positional embedding that is a function of the distance between nodes in your graph representation?

Comment: @JohnSt.John can you please explain in a bit more detail in an answer. Also can you please refer to an implementation if possible.

Comment: Done, hopefully that was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure that this solution would work for your problem, however I'll take a stab at it, and hopefully this helps!

One of my favorite resources so far for learning about transformers is this post http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html. I was able to follow along in a jupyter notebook and the only changes I remember I had to make to get it working were removing references to Variable. There is a section in there called **Positional Encoding** which may be relevant for what you want to do. Some people alternatively call this Positional Embedding. The choice of positional encoding is somewhat flexible. I have seen projects, such as Enformer from DeepMind (https://github.com/deepmind/deepmind-research/tree/master/enformer), which use custom position embeddings for the DNA sequence domain, which is centered in the middle of a sequence and extends out to the sides.

The above implementation/paper was very helpful for learning. Once I was ready to implement a transformer for a project I was working on, I found this implementation in the pytorch examples package a great place to start. In there you can see the class for the positional embedding and modify that as needed. https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/main/word_language_model

Now for your specific problem I did some googling for positional embedding/encoding and graph transformer, and I found a project that looks promising https://github.com/inria-thoth/GraphiT. Maybe that just does what you want, and their paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.05667 may have some useful background for you.

Hopefully these pointers help in your search!

Comment: could there be different kind of edges using "Positional Embedding?